# Nestjs Microservices Deployment on AWS

Tags: microservices, nestjs

I have deployed a Nestjs based microservice on AWS. It consists of a gateway which routes to a specific user microservice using TCP transport

**Current Architecture:**
I have a load balancer that is in front of the gateway microservice and all requests are processed through it.
I can access the gateway after creating a dummy route on it to test but the gateway is unable to redirect to the particular user microservice running on a certain port.

**Below is the client proxy on my gateway to the user microservice**

```
export const user = ClientProxyFactory.create({
  transport: Transport.TCP,
  options: {
    host: 'AWSLoadBalancer',
    port: 3001,
  },
});
```

**Below is the user microservice settings:**

```
const microserviceOptions = {
  transport: Transport.TCP,
  options: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 3001,
  },
};
```

I have given necessary port connections on AWS  for redirecting to the particular ec2 container.
Is there any specific routing required for target groups on AWS?I am fairly new and a noob in this particular case for aws.

Do we need the gateway as the load balancer does exactly that routing? I have searched the web for an example for nestjs microservices deployment but have not found any, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have referred to this aws article for microservices deployment: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/break-monolith-app-microservices-ecs-docker-ec2/module-four/

[image]

Comment: We solved the issue by adding the load balancer only in front of the gateway and handling the client proxy for the microservices from the gateway by adding a DNS for the load balancer as we mapped the gateway to the DNS port.

Comment: i have the same issue can you explain little more how you solved this plz